# getting value instead of text in within the formula - Microsoft excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need a solution for my problem. My problem is, while using "IF" we can set the output as a text, instead can we get the output as one of the cell values?

As I have about 121000 rows, it will be a hell to do it manually.

hope you guys understood the question. sample is enclosed in the image.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/satbT.png)

I have condition with it. If both the cells contain same value or different value, that value in the D Col has to be taken.

Comment: Use values instead of strings in your of statement. If(c2=d2, c2, d2)

Comment: Please, provide example of the code you try to run.

Comment: Your image has the cell addresses in column E.  If you're successfully returning these, then `=INDIRECT(cell ref as text)` will turn that text into a real reference.  E.g. E2 contains the text C2, so `=INDIRECT(E2)` will return the value in C2 (25mg).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `""` to the cell value `C2` or `D2` like `"C2"` will return the cell address as a `text`. So your formula should be,

```
=IF(C2=D2,C2,D2)
```